# How old is a "knabino"?

Tags: word-meaning

In English, the word *girl* is used for children but also teenagers and young women (let's say 20-25).

In Spanish, I learned that the word *niña* is only used for kids, I might guess something like up to the age of ten.

How should I use the word *knabino*? Only for children, or for young women too?

Also, if I can't use knabino for young women, what should I call them?

(Same goes for *knabo*, but I don't think the English *boy* is as widely used as *girl*.)

Comment: Native speakers, please comment to let me know how correct my assumptions are.

Comment: In English, we can say girls to mean females but it depends on context. So be careful when searching TOR.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to your question is highly dependent on culture. Even within a single language and single country people disagree about when to stop calling a young female a "girl" and whether than happens at the same age for young males.

When in doubt of what somebody means, ask.

A good guide would be to treat males and females the same. Here's how I break it down.

- knabo/knabino - 0-18 years
- junulo/junulino - 15-25 years
- viro/virino - 18+

But don't be shocked or surprised to see people doing it differently.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, the words refer to children who have not completed puberty.

I think, if you want to be very colloquial, it is probably less confusing to say ***ulo*** and ***ulino***. If someone pointed out *tiun knabon* I would be looking round for a child.

However, the words *knabo* and *knabino* were used by Zamenhof with roughly the same freedom with which *boy* and *girl* are used in English.

The *Plena Ilustrita Vortaro* gives examples:

> - *Knaboj! Nun venis la momento! Ni estas perditaj, aŭ ni devas batali kiel pafvunditaj aproj.*
> - Boys! Now the moment has come! We must fight like wounded boars, or we are lost.
>
> (From Act II of *La Rabistoj*. It is an aside, but Charles Moor is mentally addressing the Robbers.)
>
> - *Sed vi ankaŭ tiam estis la plej bela knabino en Viborg, kaj tio signifas tre multe, ĉar tie mi ĉiam trovis la knabinojn la plej belaj.*
> - But even then, you were the most beautiful girl in Viborg, and that's saying a lot, for I always considered the girls of Viborg to be the most beautiful.
>
> (From Andersen's story *Historio el la dunoj*. The speaker is an old man addressing his wife.)

Answer (score 3):

About the age of 12 or less.

> Infano: Homido kontraste al plenkreskinta homo, ĝis la 12a jaro proksimume. http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/infan.html#infan.0o
>
> Knabo: Virseksa infano - http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/knab.html#knab.0o
>
> Knabino: Inseksa infano - http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/knab.html#knab.0o

To describe a woman or a man it would be **Virino** and **Viro**